# Solr count distinct of specific field on group

Tags: sql, search, solr, bigdata, cloudera

Using SOLR, I have indexed device specific events. Each event containins a MAC address (deviceID) and a date. I would like to compute the distinct number of devices per day. I have tried the following code based on the Stats component but it seems that the Distinct part does not work.

```
.../solr/collectionVRtft_shard1_replica1/
query?q=":"
facet=true&
facet.field=date
&facet.stat=stbCount:unique(deviceID)

SQL equivalent code would be:
SELECT date, count(DISTINCT deviceID)
FROM...
GROUP BY date;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does you date field include time information?  You could perhaps convert this to date only in the DISTINCT clause

Comment: Sorry for the typo mistakes :) I have updated the code. Date field includes dates in this format "YYYYmmDD"

Comment: Your new edits make more sense :)  What error msg/output do you get?

Comment: I do not get any error. It is just that my counts are not unique. "facet_counts": {
"facet_queries": {},
"facet_fields": {
"date": [
"20141023",
308,
"20141022",
103,
"20000101",
0
]
}

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814000/how-to-select-distinct-field-values-using-solr