# How to use countDistinct to get distinct values grouped by ... without using json.facet

Tags: solr, banana, silk

Using solr 5.2.1 I'm trying to do something that in sql would look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(SESSION_ID)), COUNTRY FROM LOG
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29483791/1641941) answer would work but uses json.facet and I would like to create a banan panel for this query without having to re write the query and filter services.

This is what I got so far:

```
stats.countDistinct=true stats.distinctValues=true/false
```

JSON response:

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "stats.countDistinct":"true",
      "indent":"true",
      "stats":"true",
      "stats.facet":"country_s",
      "fq":"serverUtc_dt:[2015-09-01T07:59:00.000Z TO 2015-09-01T07:59:01.000Z]",
      "rows":"0",
      "wt":"json",
      "stats.distinctValues":"false",
      "stats.field":"sessionid_s"}},
```

It does not matter if distinctValues is true or false, no `countDistinct` value is provided in the result.

The following:

```
stats.calcdistinct=true
```

JSON response:

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":7,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "stats.calcdistinct":"true",
      "indent":"true",
      "stats":"true",
      "stats.facet":"country_s",
      "fq":"serverUtc_dt:[2015-09-01T07:59:00.000Z TO 2015-09-01T07:59:01.000Z]",
      "rows":"0",
      "wt":"json",
      "stats.distinctValues":"false",
      "stats.field":"sessionid_s"}},
```

This seems to be doing what I want but adds hundreds of thoudsands of distinctValues to the result.

According to the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component) calcdistinct would set countDistinct and distinctValues to true but replacing calcdistinct with countDistinct and distinctValues true does not do the same thing.

Is there a way to get the count distinct without getting the hundreds of thousands of distinct values as well?

Can this be done without using facet.json?

Comment: Could you add the json.facet-values as a requestHandler with those values hardcoded in on the server side?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for your reply, I will probably solve it with a custom panel, first have to get silk (as this is the newer banana I guess) and tinker with it. Was hoping I missed and have a simpler solution. The query and filter services would not be affected if the panel adds a json.facet to the url after they are done.

Comment: were you able to integrate the query output to a panel in banana? I am struck with the same issue of getting so many distinct values.

Comment: @HMR  hi,guys,have you solved this problem?what your solution?i'm facting the same problme.thanks in advance.

Comment: @zhouxiang Requirements have changed and we don't use solr for this anymore.

Comment: @HMR thank you very much.i finally resolve this by using local parameters, which is added since version 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the stats.field param to solve this, the distinctValues or countDistinct can't be used directly.

In my problem I need only the distinct count of the primary domains.

```
"params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "stats.calcdistinct":"true",
      "indent":"true",
      "stats":"true",
      "rows":"0",
      "wt":"json",
      "stats.field":["{!key=c_primary_domain}c_primary_domain",
        "{!distinctValues=false}c_primary_domain"]}},
```