# solr getting distinct records values

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, solr, lucene

```
{ 
   'companyName' : 'xyz',
   'title'       : 'xyz acquired companyB',
   'source'      : 'google.com'
},
{ 
   'companyName' : 'xyz',
   'title'       : 'xyz acquired companyB'
   'source'      : 'bing.com'
}
```

Above is the structure of my SOLR document.

The requirement which I have is, I have to group the document by 'companyName' and fetch only unique results of 'title'.

The result has to be something like this

```
 "groups":[{
    "groupValue":"xyz",
    "doclist":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
        {
            'companyName' : 'xyz',
            'title'       : 'xyz acquired companyB',
            'source'      : 'google.com'
        }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

I tried what is specified in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814000/how-to-select-distinct-field-values-using-solr). But I'm unable to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Result Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) - which is a variant of faceting.

```
&group=true&group.field=companyName
```

This seems to match the output you're suggesting.