# count distinct in solr without command line cURL

Tags: php, curl, solr

There's a perfectly good answer for how to get a unique count in solr from their website, http://yonik.com/solr-count-distinct/, and from this SO answer: [How to select distinct field values using Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814000/how-to-select-distinct-field-values-using-solr)

My issue is that I do not understand how to translate this cURL syntax into PHP, which is what I'm coding in.

The official example seems easy enough to follow from a *what's going on in this code* perspective:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/query -d '
q=*:*&
json.facet={
  x : "unique(manu_exact)"    // manu_exact is the manufacturer indexed as a single string
}'
```

However, I'm only familiar with two ways of submitting a solr query to my server using PHP.  The first, using a direct URL:

```
$url = "localhost:8983/solr/asdf/select?q=*:*";
$Q = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($Q, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);        
curl_setopt($Q, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$rawData = curl_exec($Q);
$data =  json_decode($rawData,true);
```

or through posting the values:

```
$url     = "localhost:8983/solr/asdf/select";
$solr_q  = "q=date_range:[2016+TO+*]&fq=title:manager&wt=json&indent=true";

$ch      = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $solr_q);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$rawData = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($rawData,true);
```

I'm running solr 5.4.1, so I know I have the ability to do json facets, but I have no idea how to make the request outside of the official example using command line curl.  How do I utilize this `json.facet` in the same manner that I'm currently utilizing solr in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always - right after you make a post on SO you find the answer.  If someone could still shed some light on maybe a *better* way for me to be doing this I would be very grateful - but this technically works as a direct URL:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/asdf/select?q=*:*&json.facet.x="unique(field)"&wt=json&indent=true&rows=0
```

or using the syntax I used in the OP:

```
...
$url    = "http://localhost:8983/solr/asdf/select";
  $post   = "q=*:*&json.facet.x=\"unique(field)\"&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true";
...
```

The things I was missing is that:

1. I had to name the json facet, (`&json.facet.x=` instead of `&json.facet=` and the `{ }` characters need to be replaced with quotation marks `" "` in order for the query to work as a URL or a POST request.

I really hope this helps someone as it has been frustrating me to no end for about a month now.....